# How do I get Postgresql to reflect changes made to a text search configuration?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to build a Postgresql text search configuration that will treat ISO dates (like "2015-02-19") as a single token. All of the default configurations include the int and uint parsers, which will break the date into several subtokens.

```
development=# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english', '2371-05-01');
alias |   description    | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-------+------------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
uint  | Unsigned integer | 2371  | {simple}     | simple     | {2371}
int   | Signed integer   | -05   | {simple}     | simple     | {-05}
int   | Signed integer   | -01   | {simple}     | simple     | {-01}
```

Using the Postgres [documentation on customizing text search configurations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-configuration.html) and the [docs on the available parser token types you can include in a config](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-parsers.html),  I have made a config that looks like it should work:

```
development=# \dF+ iso_dates
Text search configuration "public.iso_dates"
Parser: "pg_catalog.default"
  Token   | Dictionaries 
----------+--------------
 numhword | simple
 numword  | simple
```

But, when I try to use the configuration, it still parses int and uint tokens.

```
development=# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('public.iso_dates', '2371-05-01');
 alias |   description    | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-------+------------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
 uint  | Unsigned integer | 2371  | {}           |            | 
 int   | Signed integer   | -05   | {}           |            | 
 int   | Signed integer   | -01   | {}           |            |
```

What's going on? Does Postgres need some other command before it will honour my changes? I've restarted the database server, but don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can see that your query wants to use unsigned and int configurations, however your custom configuration `iso_dates` is only set up for `numword` and `numhword`.  Something along the lines of the following might get you what you're looking for.

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english
ALTER MAPPING FOR numword, numhword, int, uint WITH iso_dates;
```